# Error starting the Jupyter notebook on Windows

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

When I write `jupyter notebook`on my on command prompt, I get an error on cmd while running jupyter. I don't understand why this is happening again and again. Therefore, it blocks to open `jupyter editor` in the browser. I have added all environment variables as usual, but it's not working yet. Could you please help to solve this? Any kinds of suggestions are welcome.

```
H:\Research\NLP\NLP Task 1>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Imran\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\nbextensions.py", line 18, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlretrieve
  File "C:\Users\Imran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "C:\Users\Imran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\http\client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "C:\Users\Imran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\email\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "C:\Users\Imran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\email\feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email._policybase import compat32
  File "C:\Users\Imran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\email\_policybase.py", line 9, in <module>
    from email.utils import _has_surrogates
  File "C:\Users\Imran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\email\utils.py", line 29, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\Users\Imran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\socket.py", line 49, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Imran\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\Users\Imran\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .nbextensions import install_nbextension
  File "C:\Users\Imran\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\nbextensions.py", line 20, in <module>
    from urlparse import urlparse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urlparse'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstall python and anaconda. Then i reinstall it again. And it works again.

Comment: What kind of problem it was actually?  I mean what was the problem do you think?

Comment: it shows  `ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.` I don't clearly understand what's the specific problem is? But after uninstall and reinstall again, it works.

Comment: Simply uninstalling and reinstalling isn't  a proper solution, however, if it works then it's fine for you. May be all `dll` files are not properly loaded at the time of your installation.